# Why no one uses the product formula for sine function to calculate $\pi$?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, pi, infinite-product

$$\sin(\pi x)=\pi x \prod_{n \ge 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$

$$\pi = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x\prod_{n \ge 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)}$$
Let $x=\frac{1}{2}$
$$\pi = \frac{2}{\prod_{n \ge 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{4 n^2}\right)}$$

The question is Why no one uses this formula  to calculate $\pi$?  Maybe I am wrong but I have never seen anyone uses this. The answer must be that this formula converge very slowly to $\pi$ and not efficient at all. But how slowly  it converge to $\pi$? How much terms it need to reach the correct first  10, 100, 1000 decimals ?

Comment: I cant speak to why (or *whether*) "no one uses" this, but it's a known formula. See Wikipedia's ["Wallis product" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $$\tilde\pi_{(m)} = \frac{2}{\prod_{n= 1}^m\left(1-\frac{1}{4 n^2}\right)}=\pi \,\frac{  \Gamma (m+1)^2}{\Gamma \left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)
   \Gamma \left(m+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

$$\frac{\tilde\pi_{(m+1)}-\tilde\pi_{(m)}} {\tilde\pi_{(m)}}=\frac{1}{(2 m+1) (2 m+3)}\sim \frac 1{4m^2}$$

So, if you want that between two successive terms the relative difference be $10^{-k}$, you need
$$m \sim \frac 12 \sqrt{10^k}$$

Answer (score 4):

> But how slowly it converge to ?

Are you not able to run numerical calculations yourself?

Let $x_N = 2/\prod_{n=1}^N (1 - 1/(4n^2))$. We have
$$
x_{100} = 3.133\ldots, \ 
x_{10^3} = 3.1408\ldots, \ 
x_{10^4} = 3.1415141\ldots, \ 
$$
$$
x_{10^5} = 3.1415847\ldots, \ 
x_{10^6} = 3.1415918\ldots, \
x_{10^7} = 3.14159257\ldots. 
$$
So it looks like multiplying the number of terms in a partial product by a factor of $10$ typically leads to just one additional correct digits in the partial product. The millionth partial product only gives us $5$ correct digits past the decimal point, which is only halfway to the $10$ correct digits after the decimal point that you asked about. In short, the numerical data point to this product expression having terrible convergence.

Comment: "

Are you not able to run numerical calculations yourself?" NO I have no idea how to do thatI don't know anything about programming or mathematical programs like matlab and I am not in college so this is something that I need to learn by my self  , btw How to start ? do you have an advice?

Comment: There is a free Magma calculator webpage that works as long as the calculation takes up to 120 seconds: http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/.

Comment: @pie Perhaps you can start learning Wolfram language. They allow free cloud access upto a certain usage limit.

Comment: @SohamSaha how to start  learning Wolfram language ?

Comment: @pie you can have a look at the [introductory tutorials](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) and can run your code online [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) after signing up for a basic plan. Don’t hesitate to ask if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 3):

It's obviously slow. Let the sequence be $x_n$ then $\dfrac{x_n}{x_{n-1}}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4n^2}}\approx1+\frac{1}{4n^2}$

Let's say you wanna have $100$ significant digits then $\frac{1}{4n^2}<\frac{1}{10^{100}}$ hence $n > 2.5 \cdot10^{49}$

Another reason is that long multiplication is *a lot* slowlier than long addition